# EXCEL VBA Loop through cells and conditionally concatenate

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have two sheets.
The first sheet contains this table:

| id | seller | state | reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bla1 | approved | not supported |
| 2 | bla2 | rejected | rejected by seller |
| 2 | bla3 | rejected | rejected by seller |
| 3 | bla3 | failed | error |
| 4 | bla1 | failed | failed to get |
| 4 | bla2 | pending | failed to get |
| 4 | bla4 | rejected | not supported |
| 5 | bla3 | rejected | general error |

The second sheet contains this table:

| id | error message |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 3 |  |
| 4 |  |
| 5 |  |

I want to loop through the first sheet's table and conditionally concatenate:
if **id** in second table equals to **id** in first table **and** if the **state** equals to **rejected/failed** then concatenate **seller** with **state** and **reason** in **error message** in second table.
The result should look like this"

| id | error message |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 3 | bla3(failed) - error |
| 4 | bla1(failed) - failed to get bla4(rejected) - not supported |
| 5 | bla3(rejected) - general error |

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Where is your code? What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who needs VBA! (If you have TEXTJOIN in Office 2019 and newer)

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IF(BITAND(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9=A2,BITOR(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$9="rejected",Sheet1!$C$2:C$9="failed")),Sheet1!$B$2:$B$9&"("&Sheet1!$C$2:$C$9&") - "&Sheet1!$D$2:$D$9,""))
```

Note:

- Enter as array formula using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER
- Format with "Wrap Text" to get multiple lines per cell
- Must have TEXTJOIN function (or added your own TEXTJOIN via VBA)